# The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.ViolationId" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sp and i am trying to pull the INSERTED value but this code triggers an error::

The multi-part identifier "INSERTED.ViolationId" could not be bound

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO REPAIR (ViolationId,InspectorId,RepairCode,Status,RepairDate) VALUES
(@ViolationId,@InspectorId,@RepairCode,@Status,getdate())

declare @GIGID int;
SET @GIGID = (Select GIGID from Violation where INSERTED.ViolationId=@ViolationID)

UPDATE MasterGIG SET LastUpdate=getDate() where GIGID=@GIGID
```

Comment: Did you define `inserted` in your stored procedure?  It is not like it is just defined (except in certain types of triggers).

Comment: What do you expect `inserted` to be? The row inserted by the preceding statement? But then you just told it what `ViolationId` to use, i.e. `@ViolationID`, so why not just use that again, like `select GIGID from Violation where ViolationId = `@ViolationID`? Why do you (seemingly) think you need to go through the newly inserted row? This is possibly a good example of an X/Y question, where you don't explain *what* you're trying to do, only *how* you're currently trying to do it. Going back to the beginning and explaining the former will probably lead to better answers.

Comment: INSERTED is special table used in trigger body (as DELETED)

Comment: We know that, but this code isn't in a trigger body; it's in an SP, and it's not clear why the OP expected it to work in the latter context or what they expected it to contain.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
declare @GIGID int;
SET @GIGID = (Select GIGID from Violation where INSERTED.ViolationId=@ViolationID)
```

with

```
declare @GIGID int;
SELECT  @GIGID = scope_identity()
```

The INSERTED table is only available in triggers.